# Embedded Jetty looking for files inside its Jar file

Tags: jsp, jar, jetty, embedded-jetty, embeddedwebserver

I successfully embedded Jetty on a test application. It can serve files without issues.
Now I want to know if it's possible for Jetty to serve files that are inside its own Jar file.

Does anyone know if that's possible?

Answer (score 38):

An example is listed on the Jetty embedding page at http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Embedding+Jetty

The trick is to create a File URL to your classpath location.

```
String webDir = this.class.getClassLoader().getResource("com/company/project/mywebdir").toExternalForm();

ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler();
context.setContextPath("/");
context.setResourceBase(webDir);
```

Comment: @phtrivier The class where you instantiate org.mortbay.jetty.Server or org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.

Comment: any idea what to do if `request.getRequestDispatcher(...).forward(req, resp)` is not finding `.jsp` files under `WEB-INF` when running from a JAR file?

Comment: The link above is out of date, and it seems with Jetty version 9.4.11.v20180605 the class ServletContextHandler does not exist.

Comment: @JRSofty that class is in jetty-servlet: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-servlet/9.4.11.v20180605

Answer (score 5):

It's pretty simple, if you throw Spring into the equation. And here it goes:

```
 ...

 WebAppContext webAppContext = new WebAppContext();
 webAppContext.setServer(server);
 webAppContext.setContextPath("/");
 webAppContext.setResourceBase(new ClassPathResource("webapp").getURI().toString());

 server.addHandler(webAppContext); 

 ....
```

That will make jetty find the necessary web resources inside the jar file.

Comment: Thanks. I did it with Maven + Assembly plugin :)

Comment: What type is 'server' ?

Comment: @WimDeblauwe org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server

Answer (score -4):

Maybe more of a hack, but aren't JAR files actually ZIPs? (not sure) Could you unzip them into a temporary folder and serve them from there?

Comment: I could, but I want a self-contained web application inside a Jar for simplicity purposes. :)

Comment: Actually jetty does this internally if you try to set a webapp folder, so he wasn't that far off.

Answer (score -8):

Found the answer and it's not Jetty, it's Winstone. http://winstone.sf.net

Comment: Down-voting because even though you're the OP, this solution really isn't a solution. And it would be an extremely rare situation where a guy stumbling upon the issue you faced would go with this solution.