# Embedded jetty - 503

Tags: java, embedded-jetty, http-status-code-503

I started with https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/embedded-examples.html#embedded-one-webapp

Then tried this [Add web application context to Jetty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390093/add-web-application-context-to-jetty) yet I'm still getting a 503.

I've created a simple index.html for testing...

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
Nothing to see here!
</body>
</html>
```

My code is...

```java
public class WebTest {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Server server = new Server(8080);

        WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();
        webapp.setContextPath("/test");
        webapp.setResourceBase("D:\\testProject\\src\\main\\webapp");
        webapp.setDescriptor("D:\\testProject\\src\\main\\webapp\\WEB-INF\\web.xml");
        webapp.setParentLoaderPriority(true);

        server.setHandler(webapp);
        try {
            server.start();
            server.join();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And excerpt from the console...

```
40:35:297 [qtp1880587981-23] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel - REQUEST for //localhost:8080/test/index.html on HttpChannelOverHttp@6a9d23d4{r=3,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=//localhost:8080/test/index.html}
GET //localhost:8080/test/index.html HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,en-GB;q=0.8


40:35:297 [qtp1880587981-23] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel - HttpChannelOverHttp@6a9d23d4{r=3,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=//localhost:8080/test/index.html} onContentComplete
40:35:297 [qtp1880587981-23] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel - HttpChannelOverHttp@6a9d23d4{r=3,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=//localhost:8080/test/index.html} onRequestComplete
40:35:297 [qtp1880587981-23] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInput - HttpInputOverHTTP@4d788b93[c=0,q=0,[0]=null,s=STREAM] addContent EOF
40:35:298 [qtp1880587981-23] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection - HttpConnection@5097ef2d[p=HttpParser{s=END,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@48d00098{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@6a9d23d4{r=3,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=//localhost:8080/test/index.html}<-SocketChannelEndPoint@4653f8a3{/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:50173<->/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=2/30000}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}->HttpConnection@5097ef2d[p=HttpParser{s=END,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@48d00098{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@6a9d23d4{r=3,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=//localhost:8080/test/index.html} parsed true HttpParser{s=END,0 of -1}
40:35:298 [qtp1880587981-23] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection - releaseRequestBuffer HttpConnection@5097ef2d[p=HttpParser{s=END,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@48d00098{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@6a9d23d4{r=3,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=//localhost:8080/test/index.html}<-SocketChannelEndPoint@4653f8a3{/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:50173<->/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=3/30000}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}->HttpConnection@5097ef2d[p=HttpParser{s=END,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@48d00098{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@6a9d23d4{r=3,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=//localhost:8080/test/index.html}
40:35:298 [qtp1880587981-23] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel - HttpChannelOverHttp@6a9d23d4{r=3,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=//localhost:8080/test/index.html} handle //localhost:8080/test/index.html 
40:35:298 [qtp1880587981-23] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannelState - handling HttpChannelState@5b7dd1e2{s=IDLE a=NOT_ASYNC i=true r=IDLE w=false}
40:35:298 [qtp1880587981-23] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel - HttpChannelOverHttp@6a9d23d4{r=3,c=false,a=DISPATCHED,uri=//localhost:8080/test/index.html} action DISPATCH
40:35:298 [qtp1880587981-23] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - REQUEST GET /test/index.html on HttpChannelOverHttp@6a9d23d4{r=3,c=false,a=DISPATCHED,uri=//localhost:8080/test/index.html}
40:35:298 [qtp1880587981-23] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler - scope null||/test/index.html @ o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@3419866c{/test,file:///D:/testProject/src/main/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}
40:35:299 [qtp1880587981-23] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel - sendResponse info=null content=DirectByteBuffer@daadc88[p=0,l=351,c=32768,r=351]={<<<<html>\n<head>\n<me.../body>\n</html>\n>>>\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00} complete=true committing=true callback=Blocker@1099ae30{null}
40:35:299 [qtp1880587981-23] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel - COMMIT for /test/index.html on HttpChannelOverHttp@6a9d23d4{r=3,c=true,a=DISPATCHED,uri=//localhost:8080/test/index.html}
503 Service Unavailable HTTP/1.1
Date: Wed, 08 May 2019 07:40:35 GMT
Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
Content-Type: text/html;charset=iso-8859-1
```

**EDIT:**

As requested

```
20:12:500 [main] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle - STARTED @20993ms ServerConnector@2353b3e6{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@cd2dae5[9.4.8.v20171121] - STARTING
 += QueuedThreadPool@qtp488044861{STARTED,8<=8<=200,i=1,q=0} - STARTED
 |   +- 19 qtp488044861-19 SELECTING RUNNABLE @ sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll0(Native Method)
 |   +- 18 qtp488044861-18 SELECTING RUNNABLE @ sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll0(Native Method)
 |   +- 14 qtp488044861-14 SELECTING RUNNABLE @ sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll0(Native Method)
 |   +- 16 qtp488044861-16 SELECTING RUNNABLE @ sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll0(Native Method)
 |   +- 15 qtp488044861-15 SELECTING RUNNABLE @ sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll0(Native Method)
 |   +- 17 qtp488044861-17 SELECTING RUNNABLE @ sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll0(Native Method)
 |   +- 21 qtp488044861-21 IDLE TIMED_WAITING @ sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 |   +- 20 qtp488044861-20-acceptor-0@22e357dc-ServerConnector@2353b3e6{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080} ACCEPTING RUNNABLE @ sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept0(Native Method) prio=3
 |   +- jobs
 += ServerConnector@2353b3e6{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080} - STARTED
 |   +~ org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@cd2dae5[9.4.8.v20171121] - STARTING
 |   +~ QueuedThreadPool@qtp488044861{STARTED,8<=8<=200,i=1,q=0} - STARTED
 |   += org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ScheduledExecutorScheduler@3dfc5fb8 - STARTED
 |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.io.ArrayByteBufferPool@c46bcd4
 |   += HttpConnectionFactory@4b553d26[HTTP/1.1] - STARTED
 |   |   +- HttpConfiguration@69a3d1d{32768/8192,8192/8192,https://:0,[]}
 |   += SelectorManager@ServerConnector@2353b3e6{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080} - STARTED
 |   |   += ReservedThreadExecutor@524d6d96{s=0/12,p=0}@SelectorManager@ServerConnector@2353b3e6{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080} - STARTED
 |   |   += org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector@140c9f39 id=0 keys=0 selected=0 actions=0 - STARTED
 |   |   |   += EatWhatYouKill@13b13b5d/SelectorProducer@1f97cf0d/PRODUCING/ReservedThreadExecutor@524d6d96{s=0/12,p=0}@SelectorManager@ServerConnector@2353b3e6{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080} - STARTED
 |   |   |       +- SelectorProducer@1f97cf0d
20:12:539 [main] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector - Queued change org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$DumpKeys@57af006c on org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector@140c9f39 id=0 keys=0 selected=0 actions=0
20:12:539 [qtp488044861-14] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector - Selector sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl@111280a6 woken up from select, 0/0 selected
20:12:540 [qtp488044861-14] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector - Selector sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl@111280a6 processing 0 keys, 1 actions
20:12:540 [qtp488044861-14] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector - action=org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$DumpKeys@57af006c wakeup=false
20:12:541 [qtp488044861-14] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill - EatWhatYouKill@13b13b5d/SelectorProducer@1f97cf0d/PRODUCING/ReservedThreadExecutor@524d6d96{s=0/12,p=0}@SelectorManager@ServerConnector@2353b3e6{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080} t=org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$DumpKeys@57af006c/NON_BLOCKING
20:12:541 [qtp488044861-14] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill - EatWhatYouKill@13b13b5d/SelectorProducer@1f97cf0d/PRODUCING/ReservedThreadExecutor@524d6d96{s=0/12,p=0}@SelectorManager@ServerConnector@2353b3e6{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080} PC t=org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$DumpKeys@57af006c
20:12:541 [qtp488044861-14] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector - Forcing selection, actions=0
20:12:541 [qtp488044861-14] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector - action=null wakeup=false
 |   |   |  20:12:541 [qtp488044861-14] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector - Selector sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl@111280a6 waiting on select
 +- keys
 |   |   |   |   +- sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl@111280a6 keys=0
 |   |   |   +- actions
 |   |   += org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector@7690781 id=1 keys=0 selected=0 actions=0 - STARTED
 |   |   |   += EatWhatYouKill@4d910fd6/SelectorProducer@26275bef/PRODUCING/ReservedThreadExecutor@524d6d96{s=0/12,p=0}@SelectorManager@ServerConnector@2353b3e6{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080} - STARTED
 |   |   |       +- SelectorProducer@26275bef
20:12:546 [main] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector - Queued change org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$DumpKeys@6bedbc4d on org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector@7690781 id=1 keys=0 selected=0 actions=0
20:12:547 [qtp488044861-15] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector - Selector sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl@3965fa68 woken up from select, 0/0 selected
20:12:547 [qtp488044861-15] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector - Selector sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl@3965fa68 processing 0 keys, 1 actions
20:12:547 [qtp488044861-15] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector - action=org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$DumpKeys@6bedbc4d wakeup=false
20:12:548 [qtp488044861-15] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill - EatWhatYouKill@4d910fd6/SelectorProducer@26275bef/PRODUCING/ReservedThreadExecutor@524d6d96{s=0/12,p=0}@SelectorManager@ServerConnector@2353b3e6{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080} t=org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$DumpKeys@6bedbc4d/NON_BLOCKING
20:12:548 [qtp488044861-15] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill - EatWhatYouKill@4d910fd6/SelectorProducer@26275bef/PRODUCING/ReservedThreadExecutor@524d6d96{s=0/12,p=0}@SelectorManager@ServerConnector@2353b3e6{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080} PC t=org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$DumpKeys@6bedbc4d
20:12:548 [qtp488044861-15] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector - Forcing selection, actions=0
 |   |   |   +- 20:12:548 [qtp488044861-15] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector - action=null wakeup=false
keys20:12:548 [qtp488044861-15] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector - Selector sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl@3965fa68 waiting on select

 |   |   |   |   +- sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl@3965fa68 keys=0
 |   |   |   +- actions
 |   |   += org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector@2e222612 id=2 keys=0 selected=0 actions=0 - STARTED
 |   |   |   += EatWhatYouKill@77eca502/SelectorProducer@3246fb96/PRODUCING/ReservedThreadExecutor@524d6d96{s=0/12,p=0}@SelectorManager@ServerConnector@2353b3e6{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080} - STARTED
 |   |   |       +- SelectorProducer@3246fb96
20:12:551 [main] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector - Queued change org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$DumpKeys@932bc4a on org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector@2e222612 id=2 keys=0 selected=0 actions=0
20:12:551 [qtp488044861-16] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector - Selector sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl@7fb8c369 woken up from select, 0/0 selected
20:12:551 [qtp488044861-16] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector - Selector sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl@7fb8c369 processing 0 keys, 1 actions
20:12:552 [qtp488044861-16] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector - action=org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$DumpKeys@932bc4a wakeup=false
20:12:552 [qtp488044861-16] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill - EatWhatYouKill@77eca502/SelectorProducer@3246fb96/PRODUCING/ReservedThreadExecutor@524d6d96{s=0/12,p=0}@SelectorManager@ServerConnector@2353b3e6{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080} t=org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$DumpKeys@932bc4a/NON_BLOCKING
20:12:552 [qtp488044861-16] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill - EatWhatYouKill@77eca502/SelectorProducer@3246fb96/PRODUCING/ReservedThreadExecutor@524d6d96{s=0/12,p=0}@SelectorManager@ServerConnector@2353b3e6{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080} PC t=org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$DumpKeys@932bc4a
20:12:552 [qtp488044861-16] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector - Forcing selection, actions=0
20:12:552 [qtp488044861-16] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector - action=null wakeup=false
 |   |   |   +- keys
20:12:552 [qtp488044861-16] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector - Selector sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl@7fb8c369 waiting on select
 |   |   |   |   +- sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl@7fb8c369 keys=0
 |   |   |   +- actions
 |   |   += org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector@7671cb68 id=3 keys=0 selected=0 actions=0 - STARTED
 |   |   |   += EatWhatYouKill@61386958/SelectorProducer@73ee04c8/PRODUCING/ReservedThreadExecutor@524d6d96{s=0/12,p=0}@SelectorManager@ServerConnector@2353b3e6{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080} - STARTED
 |   |   |       +- SelectorProducer@73ee04c8
20:12:557 [main] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector - Queued change org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$DumpKeys@d29f28 on org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector@7671cb68 id=3 keys=0 selected=0 actions=0
20:12:558 [qtp488044861-17] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector - Selector sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl@2b9c7198 woken up from select, 0/0 selected
20:12:558 [qtp488044861-17] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector - Selector sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl@2b9c7198 processing 0 keys, 1 actions
20:12:558 [qtp488044861-17] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector - action=org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$DumpKeys@d29f28 wakeup=false
20:12:559 [qtp488044861-17] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill - EatWhatYouKill@61386958/SelectorProducer@73ee04c8/PRODUCING/ReservedThreadExecutor@524d6d96{s=0/12,p=0}@SelectorManager@ServerConnector@2353b3e6{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080} t=org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$DumpKeys@d29f28/NON_BLOCKING
20:12:559 [qtp488044861-17] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill - EatWhatYouKill@61386958/SelectorProducer@73ee04c8/PRODUCING/ReservedThreadExecutor@524d6d96{s=0/12,p=0}@SelectorManager@ServerConnector@2353b3e6{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080} PC t=org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$DumpKeys@d29f28
20:12:559 [qtp488044861-17] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector - Forcing selection, actions=0
20:12:559 [qtp488044861-17] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector - action=null wakeup=false
20:12:559 [qtp488044861-17] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector - Selector sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl@2b9c7198 waiting on select
 |   |   |   +- keys
 |   |   |   |   +- sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl@2b9c7198 keys=0
 |   |   |   +- actions
 |   |   += org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector@68c72235 id=4 keys=0 selected=0 actions=0 - STARTED
 |   |   |   += EatWhatYouKill@49dc7102/SelectorProducer@6b8ca3c8/PRODUCING/ReservedThreadExecutor@524d6d96{s=0/12,p=0}@SelectorManager@ServerConnector@2353b3e6{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080} - STARTED
 |   |   |       +- SelectorProducer@6b8ca3c8
20:12:565 [main] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector - Queued change org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$DumpKeys@2fd1433e on org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector@68c72235 id=4 keys=0 selected=0 actions=0
20:12:566 [qtp488044861-18] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector - Selector sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl@34aae006 woken up from select, 0/0 selected
20:12:567 [qtp488044861-18] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector - Selector sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl@34aae006 processing 0 keys, 1 actions
20:12:567 [qtp488044861-18] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector - action=org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$DumpKeys@2fd1433e wakeup=false
20:12:567 [qtp488044861-18] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill - EatWhatYouKill@49dc7102/SelectorProducer@6b8ca3c8/PRODUCING/ReservedThreadExecutor@524d6d96{s=0/12,p=0}@SelectorManager@ServerConnector@2353b3e6{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080} t=org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$DumpKeys@2fd1433e/NON_BLOCKING
20:12:567 [qtp488044861-18] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill - EatWhatYouKill@49dc7102/SelectorProducer@6b8ca3c8/PRODUCING/ReservedThreadExecutor@524d6d96{s=0/12,p=0}@SelectorManager@ServerConnector@2353b3e6{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080} PC t=org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$DumpKeys@2fd1433e
20:12:568 [qtp488044861-18] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector - Forcing selection, actions=0
 |   |   |  20:12:568 [qtp488044861-18] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector - action=null wakeup=false
 +- 20:12:568 [qtp488044861-18] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector - Selector sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl@34aae006 waiting on select
keys
 |   |   |   |   +- sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl@34aae006 keys=0
 |   |   |   +- actions
 |   |   += org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector@34f7cfd9 id=5 keys=0 selected=0 actions=0 - STARTED
 |   |       += EatWhatYouKill@10959ece/SelectorProducer@3a6bb9bf/PRODUCING/ReservedThreadExecutor@524d6d96{s=0/12,p=0}@SelectorManager@ServerConnector@2353b3e6{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080} - STARTED
 |   |           +- SelectorProducer@3a6bb9bf
20:12:572 [main] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector - Queued change org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$DumpKeys@29d89d5d on org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector@34f7cfd9 id=5 keys=0 selected=0 actions=0
20:12:572 [qtp488044861-19] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector - Selector sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl@63f3b36b woken up from select, 0/0 selected
20:12:572 [qtp488044861-19] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector - Selector sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl@63f3b36b processing 0 keys, 1 actions
20:12:572 [qtp488044861-19] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector - action=org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$DumpKeys@29d89d5d wakeup=false
20:12:573 [qtp488044861-19] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill - EatWhatYouKill@10959ece/SelectorProducer@3a6bb9bf/PRODUCING/ReservedThreadExecutor@524d6d96{s=0/12,p=0}@SelectorManager@ServerConnector@2353b3e6{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080} t=org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$DumpKeys@29d89d5d/NON_BLOCKING
20:12:573 [qtp488044861-19] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill - EatWhatYouKill@10959ece/SelectorProducer@3a6bb9bf/PRODUCING/ReservedThreadExecutor@524d6d96{s=0/12,p=0}@SelectorManager@ServerConnector@2353b3e6{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080} PC t=org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$DumpKeys@29d89d5d
20:12:573 [qtp488044861-19] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector - Forcing selection, actions=0
 |   |      20:12:573 [qtp488044861-19] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector - action=null wakeup=false
 +- 20:12:573 [qtp488044861-19] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector - Selector sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl@63f3b36b waiting on select
keys
 |   |       |   +- sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl@63f3b36b keys=0
 |   |       +- actions
 |   +- sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8080]
 |   +- qtp488044861-20-acceptor-0@22e357dc-ServerConnector@2353b3e6{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
 += o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@1372ed45{/test,file:///D:/testProject/src/main/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE} - STARTED
 |   += org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler1786364562==dftMaxIdleSec=1800 - STARTED
 |   |   += org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler@27c6e487 - STARTED
 |   |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.security.DefaultAuthenticatorFactory@49070868
 |   |   |   += org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@7364985f - STARTED
 |   |   |   |   += org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ListenerHolder@223d2c72 - STARTED
 |   |   |   |   += org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ListenerHolder@4ec4f3a0 - STARTED
 |   |   |   |   += default@5c13d641==org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet,jsp=null,order=0,inst=true - STARTED
 |   |   |   |   |   +- aliases=false
 |   |   |   |   |   +- dirAllowed=true
 |   |   |   |   |   +- maxCacheSize=256000000
 |   |   |   |   |   +- maxCachedFileSize=200000000
 |   |   |   |   |   +- welcomeServlets=false
 |   |   |   |   |   +- useFileMappedBuffer=true
 |   |   |   |   |   +- acceptRanges=true
 |   |   |   |   |   +- etags=false
 |   |   |   |   |   +- maxCachedFiles=2048
 |   |   |   |   |   +- redirectWelcome=false
 |   |   |   |   += jsp@19c47==org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.NoJspServlet,jsp=null,order=0,inst=true - STARTED
 |   |   |   |   |   +- fork=false
 |   |   |   |   |   +- compilerSourceVM=1.7
 |   |   |   |   |   +- logVerbosityLevel=DEBUG
 |   |   |   |   |   +- compilerTargetVM=1.7
 |   |   |   |   |   +- xpoweredBy=false
 |   |   |   |   +- [/]=>default
 |   |   |   |   +- [*.jsp, *.jspf, *.jspx, *.xsp, *.JSP, *.JSPF, *.JSPX, *.XSP]=>jsp
 |   |   |   |   += faces-servlet@3b85952e==javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet,jsp=null,order=1,inst=false - STARTED
 |   |   |   |   +- [*.xhtml]=>faces-servlet
 |   |   |   +> null
 |   |   |   +> null
 |   |   |   +> null
 |   |   |   +> []
 |   |   |   +> /={TRACE={RoleInfo,F,C[],None}, TRACE.omission={RoleInfo[],None}}
 |   |   += org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.DefaultSessionCache@4d5d943d[evict=-1,removeUnloadable=false,saveOnCreate=false,saveOnInactiveEvict=false] - STARTED
 |   |   |   += org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.NullSessionDataStore@3270d194[passivating=false,graceSec=3600] - STARTED
 |   |   +~ org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.DefaultSessionIdManager@14cd1699[worker=node0] - STARTED
 |   += org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ErrorPageErrorHandler@5d20e46 - STARTED
 |   +> WebAppClassLoader=282821294@10db82ae
 |   |   +- sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2
 |   +> Systemclasses o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@1372ed45{/test,file:///D:/testProject/src/main/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}
 |   |   +- java.
 |   |   +- javax.
 |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.continuation.
 |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.jaas.
 |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.jmx.
 |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.
 |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
 |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet
 |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.PushCacheFilter
 |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.PushSessionCacheFilter
 |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.util.annotation.
 |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.
 |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.
 |   |   +- org.w3c.
 |   |   +- org.xml.
 |   +> Serverclasses o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@1372ed45{/test,file:///D:/testProject/src/main/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}
 |   |   +- -org.eclipse.jetty.alpn.
 |   |   +- -org.eclipse.jetty.apache.
 |   |   +- -org.eclipse.jetty.continuation.
 |   |   +- -org.eclipse.jetty.jaas.
 |   |   +- -org.eclipse.jetty.jmx.
 |   |   +- -org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.
 |   |   +- -org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.
 |   |   +- -org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionData
 |   |   +- -org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet
 |   |   +- -org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.NoJspServlet
 |   |   +- -org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.listener.
 |   |   +- -org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.
 |   |   +- -org.eclipse.jetty.util.annotation.
 |   |   +- -org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.
 |   |   +- -org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.
 |   |   +- org.eclipse.jdt.
 |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.
 |   |   +- org.objectweb.asm.
 |   +> Configurations o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@1372ed45{/test,file:///D:/testProject/src/main/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}
 |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration@78b729e6
 |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration@43301423
 |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaInfConfiguration@1ab3a8c8
 |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.FragmentConfiguration@333291e3
 |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration@479d31f3
 |   +> Handler attributes o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@1372ed45{/test,file:///D:/testProject/src/main/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}
 |   |   +- javax.servlet.context.tempdir=C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\Temp\jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-webapp-_test-any-7857156332074108835.dir
 |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.tlds=[]
 |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.resources=[]
 |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.server.Executor=QueuedThreadPool@qtp488044861{STARTED,8<=8<=200,i=1,q=0}
 |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.webFragments={}
 |   +> Context attributes o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@1372ed45{/test,file:///D:/testProject/src/main/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}
 |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.util.DecoratedObjectFactory=org.eclipse.jetty.util.DecoratedObjectFactory[decorators=1]
 |   |   +- resourceCache=ResourceCache[null,org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet@45c7e403]@890545344
 |   +> Initparams o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@1372ed45{/test,file:///D:/testProject/src/main/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}
 += org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ErrorHandler@45f45fa1 - STARTED
 +- {}
 +- {}
 +- {}
 += org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.DefaultSessionIdManager@14cd1699[worker=node0] - STARTED
 |   += org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HouseKeeper@1bb5a082[interval=600000, ownscheduler=true] - STARTED
 +> sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2
     +- file:/D:/testProject/target/classes/
     +- file:/C:/Users/rober/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.26/slf4j-api-1.7.26.jar
     +- file:/C:/Users/rober/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-simple/1.7.26/slf4j-simple-1.7.26.jar
     +- file:/C:/Users/rober/.m2/repository/com/ghgande/j2mod/2.5.3/j2mod-2.5.3.jar
     +- file:/C:/Users/rober/.m2/repository/com/fazecast/jSerialComm/2.3.0/jSerialComm-2.3.0.jar
     +- file:/C:/Users/rober/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/kura/jdk.dio/1.0.100/jdk.dio-1.0.100.jar
     +- file:/C:/Users/rober/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/kura/org.eclipse.soda.dk.comm/1.2.100/org.eclipse.soda.dk.comm-1.2.100.jar
     +- file:/C:/Users/rober/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/tycho/org.eclipse.osgi/3.8.1.v20120830-144521/org.eclipse.osgi-3.8.1.v20120830-144521.jar
     +- file:/C:/Users/rober/.m2/repository/com/sun/faces/jsf-api/2.1.7/jsf-api-2.1.7.jar
     +- file:/C:/Users/rober/.m2/repository/com/sun/faces/jsf-impl/2.1.7/jsf-impl-2.1.7.jar
     +- file:/C:/Users/rober/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-server/9.4.8.v20171121/jetty-server-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
     +- file:/C:/Users/rober/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-http/9.4.8.v20171121/jetty-http-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
     +- file:/C:/Users/rober/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-util/9.4.8.v20171121/jetty-util-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
     +- file:/C:/Users/rober/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-io/9.4.8.v20171121/jetty-io-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
     +- file:/C:/Users/rober/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-webapp/9.4.8.v20171121/jetty-webapp-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
     +- file:/C:/Users/rober/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-xml/9.4.8.v20171121/jetty-xml-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
     +- file:/C:/Users/rober/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-servlet/9.4.8.v20171121/jetty-servlet-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
     +- file:/C:/Users/rober/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-security/9.4.8.v20171121/jetty-security-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
     +- file:/C:/Users/rober/.m2/repository/javax/el/javax.el-api/2.2.4/javax.el-api-2.2.4.jar
     +- file:/C:/Users/rober/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.1.0/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar
     +- file:/D:/work/eclipses/GV_Services/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/221/0/.cp/lib/javaagent-shaded.jar
     +- sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader@501edcf1
         +- file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jre1.8.0_211/lib/ext/access-bridge-64.jar
         +- file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jre1.8.0_211/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar
         +- file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jre1.8.0_211/lib/ext/dnsns.jar
         +- file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jre1.8.0_211/lib/ext/jaccess.jar
         +- file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jre1.8.0_211/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar
         +- file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jre1.8.0_211/lib/ext/localedata.jar
         +- file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jre1.8.0_211/lib/ext/nashorn.jar
         +- file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jre1.8.0_211/lib/ext/sunec.jar
         +- file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jre1.8.0_211/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar
         +- file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jre1.8.0_211/lib/ext/sunmscapi.jar
         +- file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jre1.8.0_211/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar
         +- file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jre1.8.0_211/lib/ext/zipfs.jar
20:12:594 [main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - Started @21092ms
20:12:595 [main] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle - STARTED @21093ms org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@cd2dae5[9.4.8.v20171121]
```

Comment: Have you tried using relative paths instead of absoulte paths?

Comment: Yes. Tried that first before following the comments in the second post.

Comment: Please add `server.setDumpAfterStart(true);` before `server.start();` and report back the dump details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that jetty won't scan classes if its used as embedded. It's not possible to use embedded jetty with annotations.

Solutions are

- Scrap annotations and use web and faces-config xml
- Create your own jetty branch and change it to look for a folder other than WEB-INF/classes
- Use jetty:run-war

Answer (score 0):

The dump shows ...

> o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@1372ed45{/test,file:///D:/testProject/src/main/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE} - STARTED

Which indicates that your webapp at `/test` started up, but ended up in an "Unavailable" state.

That's why you are getting a 503 error, Jetty Server will respond with a 503 if the context is labelled as UNAVAILABLE. (never even attempting to communicate with your webapp)

Next we need to pay attention to the startup logging of your webapp, something has thrown an error during the deployment and/or initialization phases of the webapp.

First upgrade to a more contemporary version of Jetty 9.4.x, your 9.4.8 is old, and also has several known vulnerabilities.  Please use 9.4.18.v20190429.

I see a few non-jetty jars, so you'll likely need to setup multiple logging frameworks to work with your slf4j-api layer.

Add the [Java Util Logging to Slf4J bridge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9117188/775715) at a minimum (to capture the jsf and el layers).  Then work on OSGi logging, and finally whatever logging the j2mod, jSerialComm, and eclipse-kura libs use with similar bridges to slf4j.