# Servlet web resources from library jar (Jetty)

Tags: java, servlets, jar, resources, jetty

I'm aware of similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33829573/how-to-get-embedded-jetty-serving-html-files-from-a-jar-not-a-war?rq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732965/exposing-resources-from-jar-files-in-web-applications-tomcat7). And yet IMHO the issue is not yet fully covered, or at least it's still not working smoothly for me :(

#### What is the need:

I'd like to build a JAR packaged library, that will be used like a shared component in several WebApps, bringing within it the server logic as well as the relevant UI (web-components). Think of a `UserService` providing servlet/resource for `login` and `signup` calls from the server side perspective, while having UI components for end-to-end solution for any WebApp in the whole eco system from the client side.

#### So far:

Seems like this requirement exactly is addressed by a feature in Servlet 3.0 spec dealing with servlet web resources found in JARs under the path `META-INF/resources`.

I, seemingly, did exactly as it said, structuring the `ui-components.jar` having `META-INF/resources/ui-commons/...` under the root and configuring the following in the `web.xml`:

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ui-commons</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>relativeResourceBase</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/lib/ui-components.jar!META-NF/resources</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ui-commons</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ui-commons/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This definition comes **before** the default servlet definition serving the rest of the regular WebApp resources found in WAR as usual.

And yet, any request for the resources in that JAR ends up with 404.

Servlet version is `3.1`.

Jetty `9.4`.

It is NOT embedded Jetty, nothing fancy, but please pay attention to the notice below regarding the maven plugin.

#### Notice:

It might somehow be related to the fact that I'm currently trying to run this whole setup with `jetty-maven-plugin`, which is serving resources from the sources.

- I've tried to drop the said JAR into the `src/main/resources/WEB-INF/lib...` manually - no success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've missed something and Joakim's answer pointed me to the right direction to find it.

In order to get resources from JARs to be served by Jetty, they first and foremost should **be scanned** by Jetty server.

By default, all the JARs in webapp's `WEB-INF/lib` are scanned. Yet, it is advised to fine tune this behavior and filter out all of the non relevant JARs to speed up the start time as per Jetty's documentation [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Avoid_slow_deployment).

So, first - be sure to review your **`WebInfIncludeJarPattern`** attribute configuration in `WebAppContext` setup and include the JAR that contains an additional static resources.

The rest of the setup for a 'foreign' JAR's resources (again, as Joakim pointed out) is identical to the regular webapp's resources, no need for any special path into the JAR as I've wrongly tried to do in my initial setup.

Answer (score 1):

Skip the `<servlet>` entries entirely.

Make sure your `<web-app>` descriptor is set to Servlet 3.0 or newer.

Example (for Servlet 3.1)

```xml
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
</web-app>
```

You MUST allow the war files to expand / extract. (this is set to true by default.  If you are declaring it false in your context deployable `${jetty.base}/webapps/<name>.xml`, or `DeploymentManager` configuration, or `WebAppProvider` configuration, then turn it back to true)

Makes sure you are using Jetty 9.2 or newer.

There's an example project demonstrating the `META-INF/resources` behavior and the `jetty-maven-plugin` at ...

https://github.com/jetty-project/jetty-example-metainf-resources

That's it, it's supported by default.  No extra work required. (unless you are doing things on your own with embedded-jetty)

If using embedded-jetty, know that this will only work with a `WebAppContext`, not a `ServletContextHandler`.

Comment: Updated the Q with servlet and Jetty versions, all correct. What do you mean skip `servlet` entires? First, I do need the default servlet to serve other statics. And... how Jetty will find the correct JAR to pick resources from? And relative path?

Comment: skip, as in don't use, as in remove from your `web.xml`.   `DefaultServlet` is provided to all webapps via the defaults descriptor, there's no need to manually declare it when using a `WebAppContext`.

Comment: If I'd like to tune `DefaultServlet` behavior, like cache control, etags, not allowing directories listing etc, `<servlet>` entry is the way to do that right (assuming no Java code involved)?