# Package Jetty web app directory

Tags: java, ant, jetty, embedded-jetty

The application is packaged as executable jar, but it can't find the `webapp` directory that is included with the fat jar. so I must include the web app in the same directory as the fat jar.

I suspect the issue has to do with this code:

```
  public void init(String host, int port) throws Exception {
    logger.info("Starting Server bound to '" + host + ":" + port + "'");

    String memory = Configurations.get("refine.memory");
    if (memory != null) {
        logger.info("refine.memory size: " + memory + " JVM Max heap: " + Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory());
    }

    int maxThreads = Configurations.getInteger("refine.queue.size", 30);
    int maxQueue = Configurations.getInteger("refine.queue.max_size", 300);
    long keepAliveTime = Configurations.getInteger("refine.queue.idle_time", 60);

    LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(maxQueue);

    threadPool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(maxThreads, maxQueue, keepAliveTime, TimeUnit.SECONDS, queue);

    this.setThreadPool(new ThreadPoolExecutorAdapter(threadPool));

    Connector connector = new SocketConnector();
    connector.setPort(port);
    connector.setHost(host);
    connector.setMaxIdleTime(Configurations.getInteger("refine.connection.max_idle_time",60000));
    connector.setStatsOn(false);
    this.addConnector(connector);

    File webapp = new File("webapp");

  final String contextPath = Configurations.get("refine.context_path","/");
  final int maxFormContentSize = Configurations.getInteger("refine.max_form_content_size", 1048576);

  logger.info("Initializing context: '" + contextPath + "' from '" + webapp.getAbsolutePath() + "'");

  WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();

  URL webRootLocation = this.getClass().getResource("/webapp");
  if (webRootLocation == null)
  {
      throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to determine webroot URL location");
  }

  URI webRootUri = URI.create(webRootLocation.toURI().toASCIIString());

  System.err.printf("Web Root location: %s%n",webRootLocation);
  System.err.printf("Web Root URI: %s%n",webRootUri);

  context.setContextPath(webRootLocation.toString());
  context.setBaseResource(Resource.newResource(webRootLocation));
  context.setMaxFormContentSize(maxFormContentSize);
    this.setHandler(context);

    this.setHandler(context);
    this.setStopAtShutdown(true);
    this.setSendServerVersion(true);

    // Enable context autoreloading
    if (Configurations.getBoolean("refine.autoreload",false)) {
        scanForUpdates(webapp, context);
    }

    // start the server
    try {
        this.start();
    } catch (BindException e) {
        logger.error("Failed to start server - is there another copy running already on this port/address?");
        throw e;
    }

    configure(context);
}
```

I found what seems to be a possible solution is this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462953/embedded-jetty-looking-for-files-inside-its-jar-file), 
am I on the right path ? how would I fix this ?

---

### Edit

I modified the code following advice given here and web searches, but now I get the following errors:

```
@-ThinkPad-T450s:~/projects/github/OpenRefine/fatjar$ java -jar openrefinefat.jar 
10:54:47.405 [            refine_server] Starting Server bound to '127.0.0.1:3333' (0ms)
10:54:47.416 [            refine_server] Initializing context: '/' from '/home/me/projects/github/OpenRefine/fatjar/webapp' (11ms)
Web Root location: jar:file:/home/me/projects/github/OpenRefine/fatjar/openrefinefat.jar!/webapp
Web Root URI: jar:file:/home/me/projects/github/OpenRefine/fatjar/openrefinefat.jar!/webapp
10:54:48.506 [                   refine] Starting OpenRefine trunk [TRUNK]... (1090ms)
10:54:48.537 [..enrefinefat.jar!/webapp] unavailable (31ms)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:277)
    at edu.mit.simile.butterfly.Butterfly.init(Butterfly.java:191)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:440)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:263)
    at com.google.refine.RefineServer.configure(Refine.java:328)
    at com.google.refine.RefineServer.init(Refine.java:242)
    at com.google.refine.Refine.init(Refine.java:117)
    at com.google.refine.Refine.main(Refine.java:111)
10:54:48.543 [          org.mortbay.log] Nested in javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException: (6ms)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:277)
    at edu.mit.simile.butterfly.Butterfly.init(Butterfly.java:191)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:440)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:263)
    at com.google.refine.RefineServer.configure(Refine.java:328)
    at com.google.refine.RefineServer.init(Refine.java:242)
    at com.google.refine.Refine.init(Refine.java:117)
    at com.google.refine.Refine.main(Refine.java:11
Created new window in existing browser session.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the [`WebAppContext.setBaseResource(Resource)`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/ContextHandler.html#setBaseResource-org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.Resource-) call.

This is how the `WebAppContext`, and the `ServletContext` finds its static resources, as well as any configuration resources that are specific to that context.

Comment: Thank you,  followd your advice I have advanced some how but get different errors